# React Reflux Stores: Difference between calling trigger() with parameters vs. without parameters

Tags: reactjs, store, state, flux, refluxjs

I have a React App with a `Reflux` Store where some components listen to the `trigger()` and then calls the `Reflux` store `getters` to retrieve its updated states. i.e.

```
var Store = Reflux.createStore({
  init: function() {
    this.filterList = [];
    ... // listening to actions
  }

  onNewFilterItemAction: function(item) {
    this.filterList.push(item);
    this.trigger(...);
  }
});
```

What's the difference between calling `trigger()` with parameters vs without? Namely:

```
  onNewFilterItemAction: function(item) {
    this.filterList.push(item);
    this.trigger(this.filterList);
  }
```

vs.

```
  onNewFilterItemAction: function(item) {
    this.filterList.push(item);
    this.trigger();
  }
```

Comment: The difference is that you either pass arguments or you don't. Reflux will trigger the action all the same. https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs/blob/719504156ddbacfce700fa21078d37c79537360a/dist/reflux.js#L630

Answer (score 1):

You can selectively update.

```js
  componentDidMount = () => { this.unsubscribe = BasicStore.listen(this.storeDidChange); }
  componentWillUnmount = () => { this.unsubscribe(); }
  storeDidChange = (id) => {
    switch (id) {
      case 'data1': this.setState({Data1: BasicStore.getData1()}); break;
      case 'data2': this.setState({Data2: BasicStore.getData2()}); break;
      case 'data3': this.setState({Data3: BasicStore.getData3()}); break;
      default: this.setState(getState());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is this pattern encouraged? Isn't getting partial store updates dangerous and buggy?

Comment: What would be dangerous and buggy about it. Its a single object with multiple properties.

Comment: What I meant was as the store gets more complex, where actions and store state mutations interweave, calling `getter()` on just a part of the store state can mean other updated store states are not retrieved. This can easily be avoided for simpler code base of course.

Comment: You can have it both ways. Pass a parameter when you only need a single update. Skip the parameter and update all.

Comment: Right. So should I mix it up? stick with just one? In what situations should I use which? Thanks a lot!